# Received Memory Warning Storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, didreceivememorywarning

I have created a view controller that contains this code in `viewDidLoad` function:

```
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View3"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View4"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View5"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View6"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View7"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View8"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View9"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View10"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View11"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View12"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View13"]];
[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View14"]];
```

When I open a new ViewController and I return to initial ViewController with this code:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I received memory warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning to the home view controller there, you're creating a new instance of the home controller and presenting it. Do that enough times and you end up with a huge stack of controllers and a low memory situation.

Try dismissing your controller instead, though it isn't really clear from your question how you get to the VC with all the child controllers in it.

Comment: How can I dismiss my controller instead?

Comment: `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller."

Comment: How can I kill "[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];" that I have instanced in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: You don't need to, assuming you're using ARC. When the parent view controller is dismissed it will get rid of all of its children.